# vNext build exits with code 1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

When I run the new vNext build ctrl+b I receive the following error

```
Error   8   The command ""C:\Users\xx\.kre\packages\kre-clr-x86.1.0.0-alpha4\bin\klr.exe"    "C:\Users\xx\.kre\packages\kre-clr-x86.1.0.0-  alpha4\bin\lib\Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager\Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.dll" build --check   "C:\api_vnext\src\Api" --configuration Debug" exited with code 1. C:\Program   Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AspNet\Microsoft.Web.AspNet.targets   136 5   Api
```

If I try to run this in the command window I receive

```
unable to locate project.json
```

My project is an empty vNext web project and I have downloaded the latest Visual Studio CTP and run the KVM upgrade to get the alpha4 components.

Build output looks like this

```
System.Exception: TODO: Error: unrecognized option '--check'
```

Comment: If I press F5 it runs without error

Comment: Looks like you logged this on the project page as well: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/159 (just as FYI to others)

Comment: I sure did Eilon, I was just about to add the link in :)

Comment: Managed to stop the error happening by removing this "--check" tag from the Microsoft.Web.AspNet.targets file in "Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AspNet". But that obviously is a temporary thing.

    <DontBuildArtifacts Condition="'$(OutputType)' == 'Console' Or '$(OutputType)' == 'Web'">--check</DontBuildArtifacts>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to Upgrade to Visual Studio CTP 4 or higher